# Find replace with Regex adding extra text

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, replace

I am using a regex within Visual Studio 2005 to turn my SQL statement into a readable string.

I am using the find expression `{.*}` and the replace expression `& "\1 " _`.

This should produce results something like:
input:

```
select *
from x
```

expected

```
& "select * " _
& "from x " _
```

The reality is I am getting:

```
& "select * " _& " "_
& "from x " _& " "_
```

Have I got my expression wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your find pattern, use a `+` instead of a `*` to ensure at least one character is matched. I think something extra is being picked up with the `*` approach, perhaps a boundary or line-break despite [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa293063%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Try this pattern instead: `{.+}`

Comment: Perfect. I wonder if the * is treating the line break as a separate match, though this would make the new insert over 2 lines.